# ImportError: cannot import name 'BackNext' from partially initialized module 'Forms_PersonalityAssesment.BackAndNext_example1'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, import, circular-dependency

I am trying to Import A function from the class BackAndNext  which has a class called BackNext in which i have back and next methods. to another file called PersonalAssesment, while doing this iam gettoing error.

i tried to acces the BackNext class methods in another file by subclass method

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

class PersonalityAssesment(BackNext):

    def personalityassesment(self):

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.get("https://talentplace.vercel.app/")
        ref.back()
        ref.next()
ref = PersonalityAssesment()
ref.personalityassesment()

from PersonalityAssesment_auto import driver
class BackNext:
    def back(slef):
        # Back Button
        back = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('a')[8];")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", back)

    def next(self):
        # Next Button
        next = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('a')[8];")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next)

ref = BackNext()
```

Comment: It's not very clear what part of your code is in which module. I'm guessing the break is supposed to be just before the `from PersonaltityAssessment_auto import driver` line, but who knows. It's generally not necessary to put every class in its own module in Python. That's a Java-ism that isn't necessary or useful here. If these two classes are so closely related that they both reference stuff core to the other, you should be putting them in the same module.